# Jquery ui tooltip doesn't displayon button tag

Tags: jquery-ui

I have this simple button tag:

```
<button class="toolb">this is a button</button>
```

This is my code:

```
$(".toolb").tooltip({ content: "example tooltip!" });
```

I hover the mouse on the button, but no tooltip is displayed. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button needs a title attribute to work, even if it's empty:

```
<button class="toolb" title="">this is a button</button>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/na4RS/)**

Comment: With jquery 1.9.2 seems working, but if I try 1.11.0 fiddle doesn't let me choose the jquery...anyway I set a title but, strangely enough, now I can see just the title..the tooltip doesn't substitute it

Comment: It works just fine with jQuery 1.11. I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sG92g/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<button class="toolb" title="example tooltip!">this is a button</button>
<script>
$(document).tooltip();
</script>
```